# When I delete all files from react app except two files package.json and package-lock.json, the shell shows me this error

Tags: reactjs, json

[{
"resource": "/home/sawan/Documents/project/frontend/package.json",
"owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#1",
"code": "768",
"severity": 4,
"message": "Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org.",
"startLineNumber": 1,
"startColumn": 1,
"endLineNumber": 1,
"endColumn": 2
}]

I am trying to create new components.